# Rotate an object (model) with rotation of an another object (hand-VR)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an object rotate with the rotation angle of the hand. It is working well and I am able to rotate the 3D model object. Unfortunately now I only want the object to rotate in its z-axis. I am trying to use `Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, rot.eulerAngles.z);` but does not work and the model rotates in all 3 axes. How do I fix it?

```
    public GameObject targetHand;

    [Header ("3D Model")]
    public GameObject powerSwitch;

    [Header ("Hand to 3D Model")]
    public float activationDistance;
    private Quaternion currentRot;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private bool offsetSet;

    void Update () {

            if ((IsCloseEnough ())) {
                Rotate ();
            } else {
                offsetSet = false;
            }
        
    }
    void Rotate () {

        SetOffsets ();

        Vector3 closestPoint = Vector3.Normalize (targetHand.transform.position - powerSwitch.transform.position);
        var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation (startPos, closestPoint);
        rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, rot.eulerAngles.z); //Not working when I do this, why?
        powerSwitch.transform.rotation = rot * currentRot;

    }

    void SetOffsets () {
        if (offsetSet)
            return;

        startPos = Vector3.Normalize (targetHand.transform.position - powerSwitch.transform.position);
        currentRot = powerSwitch.transform.rotation;

        offsetSet = true;
    }

    bool IsCloseEnough () {
        if (Mathf.Abs (Vector3.Distance (targetHand.transform.position, powerSwitch.transform.position)) < activationDistance)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to clamp the rotation around that Axis.

I make an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to Clamp each Axis like this, making the functionality available anywhere within the project.

```
public static class MyExtensions // Name it what you like I just use this
{
    public static Quaternion ClampRotationAroundZAxis(this Quaternion q)
    {
        if (!Mathf.Approximately(q.w, 0f)) // Cannot divide by 0f
        {
            // Check values are not 0f before trying to divide them
            q.x = !Mathf.Approximately(q.x, 0f) ? q.x /= q.w : q.x;
            q.y = !Mathf.Approximately(q.y, 0f) ? q.y /= q.w : q.y;
            q.z = !Mathf.Approximately(q.z, 0f) ? q.z /= q.w : q.z;
            q.w = 1f;
        }
        
        // Clamp other rotations
        q.x = 0f;
        q.y = 0f;

        return q; // Return self
    }
}

// Usage
rotation.ClampRotationAroundZAxis();
```

*Edit: Show usage to OP*

You can get it to match it like this if I have them the correct way round otherwise swap order when setting the `dir`

```
Vector3 dir = (powerSwitch.transform.position - targetHand.transform.position).normalized;
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir, Vector3.up).ClampRotationAroundZAxis();
powerSwitch.transform.rotation = rot;
```

Comment: Should I be calling this under my Rotate() function?

Comment: You could set the `rot` with it like so `var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation (startPos, closestPoint).ClampRotationAroundZAxis()`

Comment: @Programmer I wasn't sure if you know about Extension Classes so I wrapped the method in one to better show it. (Its just a file with a static class that you add the static extension methods to)

Comment: I added your extension class and I am calling it the way you mentioned ```var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation (startPos, closestPoint).ClampRotationAroundZAxis()``` but still it is not able to clamp it and all the 3 axes are fluctuating.

Comment: The Fluctuation might be from it being too close and flipping from one side to the other, as for it not Clamping I have no idea what you've done wrong as I just double check it and it works

Comment: @Programmer I've added how I tested it in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can not believe how simple it is.

To rotate things JUST `.z` axies you should keep other axies. Example :

```
Transform target;

transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, target.eularAngles.z);
```

Just using targets z.

Comment: I tried that before making it (0, 0, rot.eulerAngles.z), and I am using Quaternion.Euler.